# Querying For Archived Articles

Tags: soql, knowledge

I am having trouble querying for knowledge articles in Archived status. I want to use a `KnowledgeArticleVersionId` to find a `KnowledgeArticleId`.

I put the Id field on a Knowledge layout, which I know is the *Version* Id.

If the Article is published, I can use the following:

```
    select KnowledgeArticleId from KnowledgeArticleVersion where Id = '[online version id]' and PublishStatus = 'Online' and Language = 'en_US'
```

and I get the `KnowledgeArticleId` no problem.

However, if in the UI, I pull up an Archived version of the Article, and use the same technique.

```
 select KnowledgeArticleId from KnowledgeArticleVersion where Id = '[archived version id]' and PublishStatus = 'Archived' and Language = 'en_US'
```

But this returns no records.

Is there anything I'm missing regarding querying an Archived `KnowledgeArticleId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query archived articles, you need to use `IsLatestVersion = false`.

Following query perfectly works for me.

```
SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId, VersionNumber, FirstPublishedDate, LastPublishedDate , ArchivedDate
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion
WHERE PublishStatus='Archived'
AND KnowledgeArticleId = 'kA11600000059bH'
AND IsLatestVersion = false
```

Refer [KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)

**IsLatestVersion**

> Indicates whether the article is the most current version. (true) or not (false). This field can be true on the online or published version, a draft version in the master language, a draft version in a translation, and the latest archived version. However, you can’t filter by (PublishState=’Online’) and (IsLatestVersion=false) because the online version is also the latest version. This field is available in API version 24.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you, I added the `IsLatestVersion` flag and the query works fine in Dev Console. However when the code runs in my controller, it returns zero rows, using the same `KnowledgeArticleVersionId` in both queries.

Comment: Check that if user is having proper permissions

Comment: I don't see any reason why this is being blocked on a permissions basis; I granted the profile "modify all" and it still didn't work. The only thing I can think of is that we may need "Manage Articles" to work with *archived* articles; but, Manage Articles is apparently not available to Community licensed users. So I think that's another topic. Thank you for your help, I will mark your response as the answer.